# Solve linear equation system by given LU decomposition and vector of constants

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-factorization

Given `L` and `U` [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) and vector of constants `b` such that `LU*x=b`  , is there any built in function which find the `x` ? Mean something like -

```
X = functionName(L,U,b)
```

Note that in both `L` and `U` we are dealing with triangular matrices which can be solved directly by [forward and backward substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution) without using the [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) process.

**Edit :**

Solving this linear equation system should be according to the following steps  -

```
1. define y - s.t Ux=y
2. solve Ly=b by forward substitution
3. solve Ux=y by backward substitution
4. return y
```

**Edit 2 :**

I found [linalg::matlinsolveLU](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linalg-matlinsolvelu.html)  but I didn't try it cause I have too old version (`R2010a`) . Is it working for anyone ?

Comment: Are your vectors and matrices symbolic? If so, you need to detail this in your question.

Comment: Also, `mldivide` is [overloaded for symbolic systems](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/arithmeticoperations.html), but won't work exactly the same.

Comment: What is mean "matrices symbolic" ?

Comment: `linalg::matlinsolveLU` is in the [Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html). if your `L` and `U` are floating point values, as opposed to having been creates via `sym` or `syms` then `linalg::matlinsolveLU` wouldn't work well for you anyways.

Comment: @URL87: I think you are confusing numeric solutions to symbolic ones...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have:

```
A = rand(3);
b = rand(3,1);
```

then the solution to the system can be simply computed as:

```
x = A\b
```

Or if you already have an LU decomposition of A, then:

```
[L,U] = lu(A);
xx = U\(L\b)
```

the [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) function is [smart enough](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html#brs10rz-2) to detect that the matrix is triangular and chose an algorithm accordingly (forward/backward substitution)

Comment: this kind of thing is useful if you have a fixed coefficient matrix `A` but many different right hand sides `b`. So by precomputing the decomposition, you might speed things up

Comment: How you know that it "smart enough to detect ..."  ?

Comment: I gave a link to the docs that explains how `mldivide` implements different algorithms and chooses the appropriate one based on the characteristics of the input matrix..

Comment: here are other questions about `mldivide` that you might find interesting: [How does the MATLAB backslash operator solve Ax=b for square matrices?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1001/386), [in matlab, what differences are between linsolve and mldivide?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5603/386)

Comment: Also worth mentioning: [How does the backslash operator work when A is full?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-172BD/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-172BD)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
A = rand(3,3); % Random 3-by-3 matrix
b = rand(3,1); % Random 3-by-1 vector
[L,U] = lu(A); % LU decomposition
x = U\(L\b)    % Solve system of equations via mldivide (same as x = A\b or x = (L*U)\b)
err = L*U*x-b  % Numerical error
```

The system of equations is solved using [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). You might also look at [`qr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html) which implements [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) instead of using LU decomposition. `qr` can directly solve `A*x = b` type problems and is more efficient. Also look at [`linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html). For symbolic systems you may still be able to use [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/arithmeticoperations.html), or try [linalg::matlinsolveLU](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linalg-matlinsolvelu.html) in MuPAD.